System of linear equations with more equations than solutions
How can I determine the solutions of a system of linear equations with more equations than solutions?
E.g., I have product A, B and C and number of coworkers D. Every day n_D coworkers produce amounts n_A of product A, n_B of product B and n_C of product C. Each product needs time t_A, t_B and t_C for production. A day has the time t_D.
Thus, the searched equation is n_A * t_A + n_B * t_B + n_C * t_C = n_D * t_D.
I have thousands of lines with entries for n_A, n_B, n_C and n_D. Time t_D is constant (a day). How do I calculate the times t_A...t_C? If my data table had exactly three lines, I could solve the equations exactly. With more, I should be able to somehow calculate average and standard deviation of each, right?

A very simple solution that solves everything is to set all free parameters to zero. I assume you don't want this. So please give some more details of what you are trying to do. Are you trying to determine the time requirements for each product, i.e., t_A, t_B and t_C? If so, your right hand side should have the total time consumed, not the number of products times a free parameter, and you could use standard linear regression.

If you are not familiar with Ordinary Least Squares, then begin there.  You can find tens of thousands of threads here on CV about this.

Least squares was invented to solve problems like this ...

Thanks for your input! OLS seems to be what I'm looking for. I'll correct my question to clarify my intention.

If I understand correctly, you have a set of equations $a_i x + b_i y + c_i z = d_i$.  To solve the set of equations with 3 unknown variables, you need 3 equations, but you have much more (several thousands).
What you need is to find $x$, $y$, $z$ which minimize $$\sum_i \left(a_i x + b_i y + c_i z - d_i\right)^2$$ This is a linear regression problem.

Thank you! It's helping a lot to know the right terms to search for.
